# Deleting chain data to start new year fresh

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, fast-sync

I guess I should start saying that I am not a developer. As a noob, how can I delete the chain data so that I can re-download the chain again using the latest Ethereum Wallet version? I have been trying to re-sync for quite a while now but it is just going extremely slow. Any help is greatly appreciated!